# How can I read the importance of mails using Perl's Mail::IMAPClient?

Tags: perl, imap

I am using [Mail::IMAPClient](https://metacpan.org/module/Mail%3a%3aIMAPClient) to connect to an IMAP server. Can someone advise on how to get the priority of the messages? I tried dumping the headers, but I cannot see where the importance is set.

Answer (score 0):

That may depend on the client the sender used.

In my eyes, the most important importance setting is the header

```
Precedence: bulk
```

which indicates messages like delivery errors for which the sender doesn't even expect a failure notice, the mail system is simply free to drop these silently if any problems occur. (A good idea to set for outbound error messages, to avoid loops.)

Then, there is a header field called `Importance` which I'm not sure any mail client uses; [RfC 4021](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021) defines `Priority`, but it doesn't yet seem to be that common in the wild (hey, it's only been out for eight years!) and then there is the non-standard `X-Priority`, which may be what you are looking for.

Note that all of these are not part of the IMAP layer, but the message headers themselves. Depending on the IMAP server, IMAP flags may or may not have been set based on them, but to be sure you see what the sender thought about the mail (or their own ego), you may need to get the actual mail headers and look there.

That being said, most people I know simply ignore these values/appraisals, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have dumped the entire message. the header contains only subject,messageid,threadindex,to,from.
I can't any of those importance,priority,x-priority in the entire mail. i am using outlook 2007 for sending messages.is there any other way to do this

Comment: Are you sure the mail actually had any priority set on the sender side? http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_471.asp says you should find three headers in that case; I only see `Importance` and `X-Priority`, but that may be from a newer Outlook version. Note: No such header is sent for "normal" messages.